# determing projected latitude / longitude from a known position

Tags: windows

Not sure if stackoverflow can help with this but I want to use excel for the following.

The purpose is to use a hand-held GPS to locate the corners of a Land Survey used in a Deed Description (known as the surveyor’s Legal Description) for a tract of rural land.

From a known latitude / longitude position how do I determine the latitude / longitude of a projected position given the distance and bearing to that point?

For example, if I am at  29* 20’ 22.77” N latitude  /  99* 07’ 45.34 W longitude and I need to determine the latitude / longitude of a point 850.5 feet South 28* 58’ 17” West, What formula do I use to determine the latitude / longitude of that projected point?  Can anyone help on this?

- = degrees

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about a small piece of land  you can assume the earth is flat - then you can just use lat and lon as X and Y

Longitude is easiest since a degree of long is the same everywhere (roughly) latitude is a bit trickier but for 30n it's approx 110.852 km/deg long and 96.486 km/deg lat